# Python UTC datetime object's ISO format doesn't include Z (Zulu or Zero offset)

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timestamp, iso8601

Why python 2.7 doesn't include Z character (Zulu or zero offset) at the end of UTC datetime object's isoformat string unlike JavaScript?

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
'2013-10-29T09:14:03.895210'
```

Whereas in javascript

```
>>> console.log(new Date().toISOString()); 
2013-10-29T09:38:41.341Z
```

Comment: Python datetime values have NO timezone information.  Try pytz or Babel if you want timezone info stored in your time stamp.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'`

Comment: Related: [How to get an isoformat datetime string including the default timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28164131/4279)

Comment: ..and the missing Z surprisingly causes some things not to work eg API call

Comment: It gets even worse, if the last part of datetime is 0, it will truncate it...

Comment: Best to go with
`>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")`
`>>>'2021-05-26T07:39:27.909116Z'`

Comment: to remove the milliseconds part, use : `datetime.utcnow().isoformat(timespec='seconds') + 'Z'`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Python `datetime` objects don't have time zone info by default, and without it, Python actually violates the ISO 8601 specification ([if no time zone info is given, assumed to be local time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators)). You can use the [pytz package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) to get some default time zones, or directly subclass `tzinfo` yourself:

```
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo, timedelta
class simple_utc(tzinfo):
    def tzname(self,**kwargs):
        return "UTC"
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)
```

Then you can manually add the time zone info to `utcnow()`:

```
>>> datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=simple_utc()).isoformat()
'2014-05-16T22:51:53.015001+00:00'
```

Note that this DOES conform to the ISO 8601 format, which allows for either `Z` or `+00:00` as the suffix for UTC. Note that the latter actually conforms to the standard better, with how time zones are represented in general (UTC is a special case.)

Comment: how do I include `Z` instead of `+00:00` ?

Comment: **WARNING!!!** `pytz` violates Python's `tzinfo` protocol and is dangerous to use! See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev thanks for the link, very interesting. Note that the changes allowing `dateutil` to work weren't implemented until Python 3.6 with PEP 495, so to say `pytz` didn't use the standard interface is unfair because the interface changed. Prior to the change the only way to make it work was the way `pytz` did it.

Comment: There is zoneinfo first class library now so no need for pytz unless you have ancient environments

Answer (score 174):

#### Option: `isoformat()`

Python's `datetime` does not support the [military timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones) suffixes like 'Z' suffix for UTC. The following simple string replacement does the trick:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: d = datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 10, 12, 0, 0)

In [3]: str(d).replace('+00:00', 'Z')
Out[3]: '2014-12-10 12:00:00Z'
```

`str(d)` is essentially the same as `d.isoformat(sep=' ')`

See: [Datetime, Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.__str__)

#### Option: `strftime()`

Or you could use `strftime` to achieve the same effect:

```
In [4]: d.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
Out[4]: '2014-12-10T12:00:00Z'
```

Note: This option works only when you know the date specified is in UTC.

See: [datetime.strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)

---

#### Additional: Human Readable Timezone

Going further, you may be interested in displaying human readable timezone information, `pytz` with `strftime` `%Z` timezone flag:

```
In [5]: import pytz

In [6]: d = datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 10, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)

In [7]: d
Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 10, 12, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)

In [8]: d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
Out[8]: '2014-12-10 12:00:00 UTC'
```

Comment: Shouldn't the separator be `T` instead of a blank?

Comment: it should be `d = datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 10, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)` in line 2. Btw., in [RFC3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339) it says that a space is 'ok' (instead of the 'T').

Answer (score 62):

## Short answer

```
datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat().replace("+00:00", "Z")
```

---

## Long answer

The reason that the "Z" is not included is because `datetime.now()` and even `datetime.utcnow()` return timezone naive datetimes, that is to say datetimes with no timezone information associated.  To get a timezone aware datetime, you need to pass a timezone as an argument to `datetime.now`.  For example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

datetime.utcnow()
#> datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 3, 20, 58, 49, 22253)
# This is timezone naive

datetime.now(timezone.utc)
#> datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 3, 20, 58, 49, 22253, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
# This is timezone aware
```

Once you have a timezone aware timestamp, isoformat will include a timezone designation.  Thus, you can then get an ISO 8601 timestamp via:

```
datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()
#> '2020-09-03T20:53:07.337670+00:00'
```

"+00:00" is a valid ISO 8601 timezone designation for UTC.  If you want to have "Z" instead of "+00:00", you have to do the replacement yourself:

```
datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat().replace("+00:00", "Z")
#> '2020-09-03T20:53:07.337670Z'
```

Comment: I like this answer because most of the others either don't demonstrate adding a `Z`, or use naive datetime objects.  I feel like using aware objects is the way to go. Once I saw the difference between `datetime.utcnow().timestamp()` and `datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp()` I decided to try to stick to aware objects.

Comment: Also, if you really want to match the value returned in Javascript, you could do this: `datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds').replace('+00:00', 'Z')`. It's a bit lengthy but maybe also easy to read?

Comment: I think this is the best answer given the API limitations, but this library really ought to have a method to achieve this. Manually replacing strings components for a very common operation feels brittle and should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 40):

The following javascript and python scripts give identical outputs. I think it's what you are looking for.

JavaScript

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

Python

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3]+'Z'
```

The output they give is the UTC (zulu) time formatted as an ISO string with a 3 millisecond significant digit and appended with a Z.

```
2019-01-19T23:20:25.459Z
```

Comment: But if `now()` is 0 milliseconds, minutes and `:` will be stripped too.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов when you run `.isoformat()`, it creates a string with a fixed number of characters including trailing zeros, so this does work reliably

Comment: @PeterVanderMeer `datetime(2021, 2, 19, 23, 21, 15).isoformat()` -> `'2021-02-19T23:21:15'`, `datetime(2021, 2, 19, 23, 21, 15, 256).isoformat()` -> `'2021-02-19T23:21:15.000256'`. Different representations. My mistake is that I wrote about minutes, not seconds.

Comment: With timezone offset you need to use `[:-6]+'Z'`.

Answer (score 33):

Your goal shouldn't be to add a Z character, it should be to generate a UTC "aware" datetime string in ISO 8601 format. The solution is to pass a UTC timezone object to `datetime.now()` instead of using `datetime.utcnow()`:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

datetime.now(timezone.utc)
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 8, 6, 6, 24, 260810, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()
>>> '2020-01-08T06:07:04.492045+00:00'
```

That *looks* good, so let's see what Django and `dateutil` think:

```py
from django.utils.timezone import is_aware
is_aware(datetime.now(timezone.utc))
>>> True

from dateutil.parser import isoparse
is_aware(isoparse(datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()))
>>> True
```

Note that you need to use `isoparse()` from `dateutil.parser` because the Python documentation for [`datetime.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=fromisoformat#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) says it "does not support parsing arbitrary ISO 8601 strings".

Okay, the Python `datetime` object and the ISO 8601 string are both UTC "aware". Now let's look at what JavaScript thinks of the datetime string. Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52869882/1953757) we get:

```js
let date = '2020-01-08T06:07:04.492045+00:00';
const dateParsed = new Date(Date.parse(date))

document.write(dateParsed);
document.write("\n");
// Tue Jan 07 2020 22:07:04 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

document.write(dateParsed.toISOString());
document.write("\n");
// 2020-01-08T06:07:04.492Z

document.write(dateParsed.toUTCString());
document.write("\n");
// Wed, 08 Jan 2020 06:07:04 GMT
```

*Notes:*

I approached this problem with a few goals:

- generate a UTC "aware" datetime string in ISO 8601 format
- use **only** Python Standard Library functions for datetime object and string creation
- validate the datetime object and string with the Django `timezone` utility function, the `dateutil` parser and JavaScript functions

Note that this approach **does not** include a Z suffix and **does not** use `utcnow()`. But it's based on the [recommendation in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) and it passes muster with both Django and JavaScript.

See also:

- [Stop using utcnow and utcfromtimestamp](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html)
- [What is the “right” JSON date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/what-is-the-right-json-date-format)

Comment: Bonus for sticking to base library functions and following up on an older post.

Comment: Bonus for appropriately identifying and addressing an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  The root issue is TZ "awareness".  `+00:00` _is_ valid ISO 8601 and works (as demonstrated) machine-to-machine.  Using `Z` is purely a presentation problem.  In OP's post, the Python example had no TZ awareness while the JS example did.  The fact JS prefers the `Z` notation is incidental.  Other answers are reframing OP's "why" question into "how" (while presupposing `Z` specifically is the goal).

Answer (score 22):

In Python >= 3.2 you can simply use this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()
'2019-03-14T07:55:36.979511+00:00'
```

Comment: Very nice solution.  For their question about the `Z`, you can clip the offset: `.isoformat()[:-6] + 'Z'`

Answer (score 12):

Python datetimes are a little clunky. Use `arrow`.

```
> str(arrow.utcnow())
'2014-05-17T01:18:47.944126+00:00'
```

Arrow has essentially the same api as datetime, but with timezones and some extra niceties that should be in the main library.

A format compatible with Javascript can be achieved by:

```
arrow.utcnow().isoformat().replace("+00:00", "Z")
'2018-11-30T02:46:40.714281Z'
```

Javascript `Date.parse` will quietly drop microseconds from the timestamp.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the string doesn't end with 'Z'.

Answer (score 7):

I use pendulum:

```
import pendulum


d = pendulum.now("UTC").to_iso8601_string()
print(d)

>>> 2019-10-30T00:11:21.818265Z
```

Answer (score 5):

Using only standard libraries, making no assumption that the timezone is already UTC, and returning the exact format requested in the question:

```
dt.astimezone(timezone.utc).replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + 'Z'
```

This does require Python 3.6 or later though.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of good answers on the post, but I wanted the format to come out exactly as it does with JavaScript. This is what I'm using and it works well.

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [1]: now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

In [1]: now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') + now.strftime('.%f')[:4] + 'Z'
Out[3]: '2018-10-16T13:18:34.856Z'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import arrow

>>> now = arrow.utcnow().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS')
>>> now
'2018-11-28T21:34:59.235'
>>> zulu = "{}Z".format(now)
>>> zulu
'2018-11-28T21:34:59.235Z'
```

Or, to get it in one fell swoop:

```
>>> arrow.utcnow().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]")
'2018-11-28T21:54:49.639Z'
```

Comment: Now you can use escape characters to make it simple. 

`zulu = arrow.utcnow().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:SSS[Z]")`

Answer (score 1):

By combining all answers above I came with following function :

```
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo, timedelta
class simple_utc(tzinfo):
    def tzname(self,**kwargs):
        return "UTC"
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)


def getdata(yy, mm, dd, h, m, s) :
    d = datetime(yy, mm, dd, h, m, s)
    d = d.replace(tzinfo=simple_utc()).isoformat()
    d = str(d).replace('+00:00', 'Z')
    return d


print getdata(2018, 02, 03, 15, 0, 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

```
>>> a = "2019-06-27T02:14:49.443814497Z"
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(a)
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 27, 2, 14, 49, 443814, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It shows the opposite, i.e. conversion from string to datetime. However it was asked to convert from datetime to string with a certain format.