# Check if a date string is in ISO and UTC format

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, datetime

I have a string with this format `2018-02-26T23:10:00.780Z` I would like to check if it's in *ISO8601* and *UTC* format.

```
let date= '2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z';
const error;
var dateParsed= Date.parse(date);
if(dateParsed.toISOString()==dateParsed && dateParsed.toUTCString()==dateParsed) {
  return  date;
}
else  {
  throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
}
```

The problems here are:

- I don't catch to error message
- Date.parse() change the format of string date to `1317826080000` so to could not compare it to ISO or UTC format.

I would avoid using libraries like moment.js

Comment: `toISOString()` is a function, and you should call it as such.

Comment: `var dateParsed= new Date(Date.parse(date));` and `if(dateParsed.toISOString()==date) {` ...

Comment: `const error;` is invalid javascript

Comment: though `if(new Date(date).toISOString()==date)` without the `Date.parse` should work too

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this - you need to actually create a date object rather than parsing the string

NOTE: This will test the string AS YOU POSTED IT.

`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MN:SS.MSSZ`

It will fail on [valid ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates like

- Date: 2018-10-18
- Combined date and time in UTC:    2018-10-18T08:04:30+00:00 (without the Z and TZ in 00:00)
- 2018-10-18T08:04:30Z
- 20181018T080430Z
- Week: 2018-W42
- Date with week number:    2018-W42-4
- Date without year:    --10-18 (last in ISO8601:2000, in use by RFC 6350[2])
- Ordinal date:    2018-291

It will no longer accept INVALID date strings

```js
function isIsoDate(str) {
  if (!/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}Z/.test(str)) return false;
  const d = new Date(str); 
  return d instanceof Date && !isNaN(d.getTime()) && d.toISOString()===str; // valid date 
}

console.log(isIsoDate('2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z'))

console.log(isIsoDate('2018-11-10T11:22:33+00:00'));

console.log(isIsoDate('2011-10-05T14:99:00.000Z')); // invalid time part
```

Comment: `2018-11-10T11:22:33+00:00` would also be ISO8601 and UTC :D

Comment: @JaromandaX what do you mean? that `2018-11-10T11:22:33+00:00` should be allowed to pass?

Comment: well, yes, isn't it an ISO8601 UTC date? (I forgot the `.000` but the `+00:00` is UTC, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't "say so" ... It was supposed to be a question :p

Comment: Javascript Dates make the inner child cry :p

Comment: I never had issues with JS dates :) I do have issues when you need a large array of regex to validate user entered dates, which is why I as much as possible force the user to use datepickers, dropdowns or sliders

Comment: Is there a javascript function that validates ISO + UTC format or should I use Regex ? Can you make the right regex to validate UTC+ ISO date format ?

Comment: My code uses a regex to validate `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MN:SS.MSSZ` and then uses date to validate that it is an actual date. What dates/times are you looking for. You must have some idea of what your input could be

Comment: Here's the date format `2018-02-26T23:10:00.780Z`that should pass .Why you are checking if date is ISO format. the regex does not do it before ?

Comment: Ok I understand why. just to optimise code I suggest to add to `if` new `new Date(Date.parse(value)).toISOString() !==str`

Comment: There is no need to test the date for validity if it does not pass the string test of the regex first - at least that was my idea. It is faster than to create the date object

Comment: exception when run with `console.log(isIsoDate('2011-10-05T14:99:00.000Z'))`

Comment: @yelliver see updated script that will catch your invalid date

Comment: If you're using typescript you need to do `!isNaN(d.getTime())` to avoid an error

Comment: Be aware that there are invalid dates that JavaScript will parse, such as February 31st `new Date('2023-02-31T01:23:45.678Z').toISOString() === '2023-03-03T01:23:45.678Z'`. The `isNan` check will not catch this. Internally, the parsing will fail as long as the day is `<= 31` and just rolls over into the next month on "overflow".
Here is a pretty solid check:
https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv-formats/blob/4dd65447575b35d0187c6b125383366969e6267e/src/formats.ts#L160

Comment: Oops, meant to say "parsing will not fail unless"

Answer (score 4):

```
let date= '2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z';
var dateParsed= new Date(Date.parse(date));
//dateParsed
//output: Wed Oct 05 2011 19:48:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
if(dateParsed.toISOString()==date) {
   //Date is in ISO
}else if(dateParsed.toUTCString()==date){
  //DATE os om UTC Format
}
```

Comment: `dateParsed.toUTCString()` will **NEVER** be in ISO8601 format - so it seems an odd thing to check if a non-ISO8601 string is the same as the passed in date ... the whole point is, the passed in date, according to the question, must be ISO8601 format

Answer (score 1):

I've improved on @mplungjan 's code to create one that also works on date-only strings like '2022-01-20'

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {string} str 
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isIsoDate(str) {
    if (str.includes('T')) {
        // this is datetime
        if (!/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/.test(str)) return false;
    }
    else {
        // this is date only
        if (!/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/.test(str)) return false;
    }
    const d = new Date(str);
    return d instanceof Date && !isNaN(d.getTime()) && d.toISOString().startsWith(str); // valid date 
}

console.log(isIsoDate('2022-01-01'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
let date= '2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z';
const dateParsed = new Date(Date.parse(date))

if(dateParsed.toUTCString() === new Date(d).toUTCString()){
   return  date;
} else {
     throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed'); 
}
```

I hope that is clear!

Comment: `dateParsed.toUTCString() === new Date(d).toUTCString()` why the extra check?

Comment: Well, no: `new Date(Date.parse('0021'))`