# UTCNow offsetting in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, utc

How would I exactly go about offsetting the timestamp returned by `datetime.utcnow()` by any amount of time such as a day?

For example:

```
now = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
```

I need the above offset by a day. Having a minor issue when my script crosses into the daylight savings time conversion but I dont need to see past it however since it loads today also it dies because the python script errors doing work on the date today now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simply add a certain delta time onto UTC add a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=3)).isoformat() + 'Z'

print(now)
```

Output:

```
2018-11-06T16:55:06.535804Z
```

---

More info on python with timezones can be found at  [Python UTC datetime object's ISO format doesn't include Z (Zulu or Zero offset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654578/python-utc-datetime-objects-iso-format-doesnt-include-z-zulu-or-zero-offset)

With 3.7 `datetime.strptime` and `datetime.strftime` even recognize `01:30` as `%z` - up to 3.6 the colon would make it crash :)

Comment: Thanks much. I couldnt figure out how to pair the two. That works perfectly.

Comment: Don't use utcnow() since it produces different values depending on the TZ of your system. Use datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) instead.