# Why does Python 3 find this ISO8601 date: "2019-04-05T16:55:26Z" invalid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, iso8601

I supply `"2019-04-05T16:55:26Z"` to Python 3's `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat` and get `Invalid isoformat string`, though the same string works without the Z. ISO8601 allows for the Z - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 12 2019, 08:15:36)

>>> datetime.fromisoformat("2019-04-05T16:55:26Z")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2019-04-05T16:55:26Z'

>>> datetime.fromisoformat("2019-04-05T16:55:26")
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 16, 55, 26)
```

[ please note the comment from djvg: "It's supported starting with [Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)" ]

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654578/python-utc-datetime-objects-iso-format-doesnt-include-z-zulu-or-zero-offset

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) clearly state what's supported.

Comment: Yes they do, but perhaps the name is misleading given that they don't work with the actual ISO format!

Comment: It's supported starting with [Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)

Answer (score 34):

I just checked [the Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=fromisoformat#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) and it isn't intended to parse arbitrary ISO8601 format strings:

> **Caution**: This does not support parsing arbitrary ISO 8601 strings - it is only intended as the inverse operation of `datetime.isoformat()`.

Comment: Ok, but then what would be the proper function to parse this string?

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs, my point exactly - i responded to jonrsharpe above with 'the name is misleading given they don't work with the actual ISO format'

Answer (score 32):

If you already know the format your API responds, you can use:

```py
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2022-04-07T08:53:42.06717+02:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

Adjust for your needs, if the string for example does not contain milliseconds, etc.

Otherwise, as the official python documentation suggests, use the `dateutil` package: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse

Comment: Wow, `dateutil` is brand new to me. This saves me a lot of time, thank you!

Comment: `dateutil` is the proper way to do ti

Answer (score 18):

Proper ISO format including the timezone is now supported in 3.11

https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solve it based in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3908349/5931672).

```
from dateutil import parser
yourdate = parser.parse(datestring)
```

It returns a `datetime.datetime` so is perfect.

Answer (score -15):

It is so simple. Just remove the last letter Z.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime; datetime.fromisoformat("2019-04-05T16:55:26")
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 16, 55, 26)
```

Comment: i think you might be missing the point somewhat

Comment: are you sure this even works correctly in other timezones?