# How to append 'Z' suffix to datetime.datetime object or replace tzinfo with 'Z'?

Tags: python, datetime

How do I append 'Z' suffix to my datetime.datetime object which has a timestamp? e.g 2020-08-08T00:00:00

Comment: timestamp+'Z'...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654578/python-utc-datetime-objects-iso-format-doesnt-include-z-zulu-or-zero-offset